# Python program to solve Movielens dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone help on using Movielens dataset to come up with an algorithm that predicts which movies are liked by what kind of audience?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/06/quick-guide-build-recommendation-engine-python/) you can build a  Recommendation Engine in Python using Movielens dataset
topics covered are:

1. Type of Recommendation Engines
2. The MovieLens DataSet
3. A simple popularity model
4. A Collaborative Filtering Model
5. Evaluating Recommendation Engines